# Clojure replace string value from map

Tags: clojure

```
(def database (atom
           [{:orderid 0 :productid 0 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}
            {:orderid 1 :productid 1 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}]))

(defn edit-order
  [param-data]

(swap! database
             (fn [old-orders]
                 (mapv (fn [order]
                           (if (= (:orderid order)
                                  (:orderid param-data))
                             (assoc-in database [:state] "deleted") 
                             order))
                       old-orders)))
                     )


 (edit-order 0)
```

I want to replace the "active" to "deleted" after I give the Order ID. I tried with assoc-in, but it doesn't work. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You are calling the function with the order-id directly (0) but in your `if` there you access param-data like a map to get the :order-id from it.

Comment: So, how should I do it, if I want to call directly by order-id (int)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. First, in your `if`, you are comparing the `:orderid` of an order entry with an `:orderid` of the `param-data`, which doesn't make sense because `param-data` a number and not a map. What you want to do is compare the `:orderid` of your order entry with the value of `param-data`, like this:

```
(if (= (:orderid order)
        param-data)
```

Next, it seems that you're a bit confused about what you're doing in your mapping function. In the else-branch of your `if`, you return an order entry, which is correct since you're mapping over the vector of all orders. But in the other branch (the "then" branch), you're trying to use `assoc-in` on `database`, which is not want you want to do, since `assoc-in` will return an updated version of your full order list. I think what you want to do instead is just use `assoc` on the `order` parameter, like this:

```
(assoc order :state "deleted")
```

Which makes the full function look like this:

```
(defn edit-order
  [param-data]
  (swap! database
    (fn [old-orders]
       (mapv (fn [order]
                 (if (= (:orderid order)
                        param-data)
                   (assoc order :state "deleted") 
                   order))
             old-orders))))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. you were right. I was a bit confused with mapping function.

Comment: I'd also rename `param-data` to `order-id` then.  `param-data` is as generic as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is right now has two issues:

```
(def database (atom
          [{:orderid 0 :productid 0 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}
            {:orderid 1 :productid 1 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}]))

(defn edit-order
  [param-data]

(swap! database
            (fn [old-orders]
                (mapv (fn [order]
                          (if (= (:orderid order)
                                  (:orderid param-data))   ;; Issue 1
                            (assoc-in database [:state] "deleted") ;; Issue 2
                            order))
                      old-orders)))
                    )


(edit-order 0)
```

Issue 1 stems from how you call `edit-order` -- there is no `:orderid` key there, it's just a number.

Issue 2 is that you are running `assoc-in` on Var that holds an Atom, while you're modifying that Atom already within `swap!`, iterating on orders stored there. Working code with both issues resolved:

```
(def database
  (atom
    [{:orderid 0 :productid 0 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}
    {:orderid 1 :productid 1 :description "A" :amount 2 :state "active"}]))


(defn edit-order
  [param-data]
  (swap! database
        (fn [old-orders]
          (mapv (fn [order]
                  (if (= (:orderid order) param-data)
                    (assoc order :state "deleted")
                    order))
                old-orders))))


(edit-order 0)
```